# Linux command for finding the system call

Tags: linux, find, command, kernel

I just start to learn Linux command, here comes a question: how do I find information about the system call 'open', rather than the executable program while using "man" command.

Answer (score 1):

System calls are on normally found in [man section 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean)

```
man -s 2 open
```

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the section of the manual where you want the manpage to come from.  By default system commands (section `1`) come first, before system calls (section `2`) or library routines (section `3`), so

```
man 2 open
```

will do the work.  Normally, when you see a reference to a man page you'll see a number in parenthesis attached to it (like `open(2)`) That number indicates the manual section you will find that thing in.

You can even test

```
man man
```

and you'll get a very good reference to how the online manual works.